# Problem with REPLACE statement and primary key in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that uses REPLACE statement, but for some reason it doesn't update row and column (in this case login) that it is supposed to update in database. I get error

```
[23000][1062] Duplicate entry '7409685' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I checked my primary key which is 'id' is primary, is auto increment, and is not null. Here is my query.

```
REPLACE INTO members
(id,login,password,email,gender,age)
VALUES
('7409685','mike','blahblah12','mike@gmail.com','Man','40');
```

But when I try

```
UPDATE members
SET login = 'mike'
WHERE id = '7409685';
```

then it updates. But I need it to work with REPLACE. Any help is appreciated.

```sql
create table script

create table members
    (
        id int auto_increment
        primary key,
        login varchar(25) null,
        password varchar(20) null,
        gender varchar(25) null,
        age int null,
    );

    create index age
        on dt_members (age);

    create index gender
        on dt_members (gender);

    create index login
        on dt_members (login);

    create index idx_dtm
        on dt_members (id);

    create index idxpwd
        on dt_members (password);

    create definer = `webuser-rw`@`10.100.165.%` trigger mapper_dt_members_AFTER_DELETE
        after delete
        on dt_members
        for each row
        BEGIN
            UPDATE sugaudqf_.mapper_update SET deleted_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where id=OLD.id;
    END;

    create definer = `webuser-rw`@`10.100.165.%` trigger mapper_dt_members_AFTER_INSERT
        after insert
        on dt_members
        for each row
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO sugaudqf_.mapper_update (id) VALUES (NEW.id);
    END;

    create definer = `webuser-rw`@`10.100.165.%` trigger mapper_dt_members_AFTER_UPDATE
        after update
        on dt_members
        for each row
        BEGIN
        UPDATE sugaudqf_.mapper_update SET updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, processed_at = NULL where id=NEW.id;
    END;
```

Comment: The docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html say that a DELETE should have done. Another weird thing is key 'PRIMARY'.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yeah I know that replace does delete, that's why I need it. But I don't know why it won't update. When I remove id from query, it doesn't show error but it doesn't update record in database either.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @PaulT. Version is 5.6.44

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE script. Does PRIMARY is not the only unique constraint in the table?

Comment: @Akina I added the script, updated the question.

Comment: 99% that `mapper_dt_members_AFTER_INSERT` trigger is a place where the violation occures.

Comment: @Akina What should I do then?

Comment: You must check does the row with this `id` already exists in `mapper_update`. Or use REPLACE instead of INSERT in the trigger too. Or INSERT IGNORE. Or remove `mapper_update.id` uniqueness.

Comment: @Akina  How to check if id already exists in mapped_update?

Comment: o_O by according SELECT query, of course.

Comment: @Akina  Yeah, but I don't know how I can edit this file, I only exported it using phpstorm. Do you know how I can change it and save those changes?

Comment: I give you 4 variants for how to fix. But I don't know your system logic, and you're the only who can decide which of these variants are applicable and what one is optimal.